# Using T4 (Text Template Translation Toolkit) to define UI States

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Looking for implementation of UI Finite State machine in the T4. 
Has anyone attempted similiar ...

Comment: +1 Interesting concept. You may want to expand your question a little.